# How to call datatable columns twice with alias name using linq in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

Alias name means in data table if we have colA,col b and colc what iam doing means iam again recreating colc and renaming as proj with same values using linq as shown below in output bro

[image]

Comment: Just like SQL, you use the `Select` clause in LINQ to specify what columns/properties.  It's not really for us to teach you how to use LINQ.  Do your research and make an attempt to do what it is that you want to do.  If it doesn't work, THEN post a question here and provide all the relevant information.  THAT is what this site is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Private Class Input
    Public Name As String
    Public Value As String
    Public Description As String
End Class

Private Class Output
    Public Name As String
    Public Value As String
    Public Description As String
    Public Proj As String
End Class

Private Sub Main()

    Dim InputTable As New List(Of Input)  'Populate this table however you want
    Dim MatchCriteria As String = "Whatever" 'Just in case you want to filter results
    Dim OutputTable = (From i As Input In InputTable
                       Where i.Name = MatchCriteria
                       Select New Output With
                          {.Name = i.Name,
                           .Value = i.Value,
                          .Description = i.Description,
                          .Proj = i.Description
                          }).ToList()
End Sub
```